# Sonata User Bundle + FOS User bundle + Custom user bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

i'm little confused..

1. I'm using sonata admin bundle in my project and i'd like to install user management for this, tell me please do i really have to install sonata user bundle? (i was using this tutorial http://domitable.com/content/getting-started-symfony-23-sonata-admin-user-bundles ) or only fos user bundle will be enought? i'm asking this becouse i want to install as little dependiendes as possible.
2. honestly the best way for me would be to use only my custom user bundle with custom user entity..(if need be only my class + FOS)
3. Do i have to use easy-extends to generate my user entity class or default doctrine generate entity is okay?
4. What about sonata ACL in this sitaution?

what is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful, relevant answer. I don't know what are your requirements, so it's difficult to answer the questions you set out.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try my best with what I have. Basically, SonataUserBundle is only useful if you want to manage the users via SonataAdmin.

FosUserBundle is simply a bundle that manages users and some actions such as login, but from the point of view of a user. That is, it does not have the tools built in for an admin to manage users.

Therefore, to manage the users, you need SonataAdmin and SonataUser.

If you easy extends SonataUser, then you could transfer your custom entity in the extended bundle. That is a way you could do it.

ACL is a complete different thing, read here for more information:http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html